# Bypass the dependency version numbers in a .NET assembly

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I am using a DLL compiled by someone else which depends on version 11 of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll.  The rest of my project depends on version 12 of that same DLL.

Is it possible to change the dependency inside the 3rd-party DLL, or somehow force it to use version 11 instead of version 12 of the UITesting DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a binding redirect in your app.config from version 11 to version 12:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll"
                          publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0"
                         newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 And here is more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You surely do have to explain how you'd get the test runner to use these config entries.  It already uses a very elaborate .config file, tinkering with it is ... risky.

Comment: Great, this worked.  I had read that file, but I didn't think it applied to my situation.  For clarification to any future readers, I thought binding redirect only worked if you were directly referencing an assembly in your project, not referencing-an-assembly-that-references-an-assembly.  It works in both cases.

Comment: @HansPassant, Simply right click the test project and add a new item, select "Application Configuration" and then it is released with the test-containing DLL.